# Binary search tree throwing error while adding node

Tags: java, binary-search-tree

I have this binary search tree that I wrote in Java. It seems to be working fine. However, upon calling multiple add calls, I am getting StackOverFlow error. I am learning to write in Java. Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
 public class TreeApp<E extends Comparable<E>>
{
    private Node<E> root=null;
    private int size=0;

    private static class Node<E>
    {
        private E e;
        private Node<E> left;
        private Node<E> right;
        private Node<E> parent;

        public Node(E e,Node<E> parent,Node<E> left,Node<E> right)
        {
            this.e=e;
            this.left=left;
            this.right=right;
            this.parent=parent;
        }

        public Node(E e)
        {
            this.e=e;
        }

        public E getE() {
            return e;
        }

        public void setE(E e) {
            this.e = e;
        }

        public Node<E> getLeft() {
            return left;
        }

        public void setLeft(Node<E> left) {
            this.left = left;
        }

        public Node<E> getRight() {
            return right;
        }

        public void setRight(Node<E> right) {
            this.right = right;
        }

        public Node<E> getParent() {
            return parent;
        }

        public void setParent(Node<E> parent) {
            this.parent = parent;
        }


    }//end of Node<E> class

    public TreeApp()
    {

    }

    public Node<E> createRoot(E e,Node<E> l,Node<E> r)
    {
        if(!(root==null))
        System.out.println("Root is already present");
        root=new Node<E>(e,root,l,r);
        size++;
        return root;


    }

    public Node<E> addNode(Node<E> left,E e)
    {

        //lets start with root
        if(root==null)
            createRoot(e,null,null);
        Node<E> focusNode=root;

        //Node<E> newLeft
        Node<E> newNode=new Node<E>(e);

        //while(true)
        if(e.compareTo(focusNode.e) < 0)
        {
            if(focusNode.getLeft()==null)
            {
                focusNode.setLeft(newNode);
                size++;
            }
            else
            {
                focusNode=focusNode.getLeft();
                //addNode(focusNode,e);
            }

        }else if(e.compareTo(focusNode.e) >= 0)
        {
            if(focusNode.getRight()==null)
            {
                focusNode.setRight(newNode);
                size++;
            }
            else
            {
                focusNode=focusNode.getRight();

                //addNode(focusNode,e);
            }
        }
        return focusNode;
    }

    public void preorderTraverseTree(Node<E> focusNode) {

        if (focusNode != null) {

            System.out.println("starting traversal: " + focusNode.getE());

            preorderTraverseTree(focusNode.getLeft());
            preorderTraverseTree(focusNode.getRight());

        }

    }

    public String toString() {
        if (root == null) {
          return "";
        } else {
          return root.toString();
        }
      }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        //Node<String> p=new Node<String>();
        TreeApp<String> ta=new TreeApp<String>();
        System.out.println("size before: " + ta.size);

        ta.createRoot("3",null,null);
        Integer i=1;
        Integer j=2;
        System.out.println("comparison " + i.compareTo(j));
        //System.out.println("size after: " + ta.size);
        ta.addNode(ta.root,"2");
        ta.addNode(ta.root,"4");
        ta.addNode(ta.root,"1");
        ta.addNode(ta.root,"6");

        //ta.addNode(ta.root,"5");
        ta.preorderTraverseTree(ta.root);
        //System.out.println("size after: " + ta.size);



    }

}
```

Comment: It throws this error after I have made 3 insertions.So,first three add calls are a success.It seems a little strange

Answer (score 0):

The stackoverflow happens because of an infinite recursive loop, caused by the `left` argument being ignored in favor of the root node.

The error occurs in your case when adding node 1, because the root node 3 already has a left child 2 and right child 4. Hence, the method does a recursive call to try and add node 1 as a left or right child of node 2, but when it reenters the method it ignores node 2 and tries to fit node 1 under the root node 3 again and this keeps going on and on.

```
public Node<E> addNode(Node<E> left, E e) {
    //lets start with root
    // if (root == null)
    //     createRoot(e, null, null);
    // Node<E> focusNode = root;        // <-- wrong
    Node<E> focusNode = left;           // <-- correct

    //Node<E> newLeft
    Node<E> newNode = new Node<E>(e);

    //while(true)
    if (e.compareTo(focusNode.e) < 0) {
        if (focusNode.getLeft() == null) {
            focusNode.setLeft(newNode);
            size++;
        } else {
            focusNode = focusNode.getLeft();
            addNode(focusNode,e);       // <-- uncomment this line
        }

    } else if (e.compareTo(focusNode.e) >= 0) {
        if (focusNode.getRight() == null) {
            focusNode.setRight(newNode);
            size++;
        } else {
            focusNode = focusNode.getRight();
            addNode(focusNode,e);       // <-- uncomment this line
        }
    }
    return focusNode;
}
```